# How do I check if login credentials is present in mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am making a small login and registration using node.js and mongodb with dependencies such as express, mongoose and body-parser.
I am not able to make the login part work. In my case, even with the wrong credentials, the login takes place. Please look at my code and help me with it.

This is my index.js node.js code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", { useNewUrlParser: true });

var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var registerSchema = new Schema({
    uname:String,
    psw:String
});
var reg = mongoose.model('reg',registerSchema);

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});



app.post("/register", (req,res)=>{
        const user= new reg(req.body);
        if(reg.findOne({uname:req.body.name})){
            res.send("Username is taken");
        }
        else{
        user.save()
        .then(user => {
            res.send("User added succesfully.")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to create user.")
        });
    }
}) 


app.get("/login", (req,res)=>{
    reg.findOne({uname:req.body.uname, psw:req.body.psw}, function(err,user)
    {
        if(err)
        {
        res.send("User not found.")
        }
        res.send("Logged in succesfully.")
    }
)});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/register" method="POST">
        <label for='uname'>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
        <br>
        <label for="psw">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <br><hr>
        <button type="submit" >Register</button>
    </form>
    <br> <br>

    <form action="/login" method="GET">
        <label for='uname'>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
        <br>
        <label for="psw">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <br><hr>
        <button type="submit" >Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if user is null, it does not return error when not found.

Answer (score 0):

`findOne` will only call back with an error if the connection to the db crashes, otherwise if the user wasn't found `user` will be `null` so your check has to be:

```
 if(err || !user) { // "if error or no user"
    res.send("User not found.")
 } else {
    res.send("logged in!");
 }
```

Additionally this:

```
 if(reg.findOne({uname:req.body.name})) {
```

won't work. Pass in a callback just as you did in the login part.

Comment: Just one more thing, in the login part, will it be app.get or app.post?

Comment: @tahseen depends on how you visit it